# Matrix derivative with complex term question.

Tags: matrix-calculus, differential

Matrix derivative with complex term question.

I have a question about how to proced with the matrix derivation where i have a complex matrix.
Supose i have a function
\begin{align}
y =  \mathrm{ln}|XX^H+\alpha I|,
\end{align}
where $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$, the operator $H$ is the hermitian (conjugate transpose) and $\alpha$ is a small scalar. I need the derivative of $y$ with respect to $X$.

With $A = XX^H+\alpha I$ the function become
\begin{align}
y =  \mathrm{ln}|A|.
\end{align}
The differential from wiki is
\begin{align}
 dy 
 &= d\ \mathrm{ln}|A|\cr
 &= \mathrm{Tr}(A^{-1} dA)\cr
 &= A^{-T}:dA\cr
 dA &= (dXX^H + XdX^H).
\end{align}

Substituting $dA$ in $dy$ led to
\begin{align}
 dy 
 &= A^{-T}:dA\cr
 &= A^{-T}:(dXX^H + XdX^H)\cr
 &= A^{-T}:dXX^H + A^{-T}:XdX^H\cr
\end{align}

From here i got stuck. I don't know how to deal with the hermitian term $dX^H$ and also don't know if i can apply some cyclic properties (because A is not square) like $A^{-T}:dXX^H = X^HA^{-T}:dX$.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A^C$ denote the complex conjugate.

Using the cyclic property of the trace (aka Frobenius product), you can rearrange the differential expression to easily spot the desired gradients.
$$\eqalign{
dy &= A^{-T}X^C:dX \;+\; X^TA^{-T}:dX^H \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial X} &= A^{-T}X^C, \qquad\qquad 
 X^TA^{-T} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial X^H} \\
}$$
Since $A$ is hermitian
$$\eqalign{
A^H &= A,\quad &A^{-H}=A^{-1} \\
A^T&=A^C,\quad &A^{-T}=A^{-C}
}$$
Furthermore, $y$ is real so you really only need to know one of the gradients
and you can calculate any other gradient using the above table
of $A$-equivalencies
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial y}{\partial X^H}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}\right)^H 
 = (A^{-T}X^C)^H = X^TA^{-T} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial X^C}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}\right)^C
 = (A^{-T}X^C)^C = A^{-1}X \\
}$$

Comment: How can i prove that $A$ is hermitian? I also didn't understand how the gradients are formed. Is like three different gradients $\frac{\partial y}{\partial X} , \frac{\partial y}{\partial X^H}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial X^C}$ ?

Comment: Any matrix of the form $XX^H$ is hermitian, as is the linear combination of such matrices. As for the the three gradients, I was merely pointing out that knowing any one of them allows you to calculate the other two.